# Golem in Prehard mode

Tags: terraria-mobile

How do I kill Golem in Pre-Hardmode? I already know how to get into the Lizahard temple. Once I was inside I summoned Golem with the Lizahard power cell, but he has 10000+ health.

What is the easiest way to defeat him?

In this picture it shows I have gone to the temple in Prehard mode.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is definitely not Minecraft.

Comment: I had no choice anyway minecraft is also my favourite game.

Comment: Actually, this is about Terraria. The Terraria tag would have been appropriate.

Comment: Srry I didn't notice

Comment: That picture is in pre hard mode

Comment: This proves that you can fight golem in Pre hard mode

Comment: If anyone thinks I killed plantera think again, Did I kill it with a night's edge?

Comment: @DetectiveRT only before 1.2.3 which mobile and console has yet to be updated too. As of 1.2.3 you can not fight Golem unless Plantera is defeated in that world and to my knowledge thee are no glitches to get Plantera pre-hardmode which unless support for mobile and console version has ceased, they will be updated to 1.2.3 at some point.

Comment: What proof do you have that you're in hard mode? Just a statement saying so does not make it true.

Comment: I will send u a photo frank

Comment: @DetectiveRT rather than send it to just one person why not edit your question with it for everyone to see

Comment: I only have molten armour

Comment: That doesn't prove a thing. Having a pre-hard mode armour set doesn't mean you're not in hard mode.

Comment: I got update 1.2.6508 for my iOS

Comment: I don't have pown hammer

Comment: What proof exactly do u want me to show

Comment: Proof is something that shows the statement you're making is true. If anything, your pictures prove you ARE in hard mode.

Comment: Even if I am in hard mode I have to kill plantera to obtain the key

Comment: For what it's worth, it is possible to reach the Golem on pre-hardmode: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Golem#Notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much easier to get better gear in hard mode to deafeat him. Trying this early in the game will be a waste of time. You won't have the armor or damage to kill him.

Comment: Sadly I did not succeed I am out of voodoo dolls

Answer (score 0):

I killed him In prehard mode I used molten armour nights edge and holyhand grenades

What I did was clear out the traps so they can't kill you then make sure his spawn is by a narrow entrance if not then make it,then you have at least 100 holy hand grenades and spawn him the start throwing them at him
Dodge his attacks as best you can and be careful cause he can 2 shot you 
If any lizards attack you use nights edge to kill them and keep throwing 
Hhg (holy hand grenade) at him until he dies then you will be op

Also to enter the lizhard temple throw bomb at door.
Pickup lizhard brick wall and convert it to lizhard brick to make your buildings indestructible.